# Does anyone know why this foreach (var item in Model) that shows data from 2 models in a single view gives an error?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model

I have two different models with their controllers joined in a single model, to then present it in a single partial view that is called from another index ASP.NET Core 5 view

This is the main **Index** view

```
@model Local.Web.Models.SoundModel
@namespace Local.Web.Views
@{
    if (ViewData.TryGetValue("ParentLayout", out var parentLayout))
    {
        Layout = (string)parentLayout;
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}

<h2>Index Principal</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <partial name="_Sounds" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the **Sound1Model** that lists sounds

```
using System;    
namespace Local.Web.Models
{
    public class Sound1Model
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the **TipSoundModel** that lists Types of Sounds

```
using System;   
namespace Local.Web.Models
{
    public class TipSoundModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public string Nombre_ES { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is the **SoundModel** Model that brings together the two previous models, to be able to consult them from a single view

```
namespace Local.Web.Models
{
    public class SoundModel
    {
        public Sound1Model sound { get; set; }
        public TipSoundModel tipSound { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the **SoundController** controller that takes care of Collecting the sounds to display

```
using System.Linq;
using Local.Web.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Local.Datos.Repositorios;

namespace Local.Web.Controllers
{
    public class SoundController : Controller
    {
        private IRepositorioSonido _repositorioSonido;
        public SoundController(IRepositorioSonido repositorioSonido)
        {
            _repositorioSonido = repositorioSonido;
        }

        public IActionResult _Sounds()
        {
            var sonidos = _repositorioSonido.ListarTodos();
            var model = sonidos.Select(s => new Sound1Model
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                Tipo = s.Tipo,
                Nombre = s.Nombre,
            });

            return PartialView(model);
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the **TipSoundController** controller that takes care of Collecting the Types of Sounds to display

```
using Local.Datos.Repositorios;
using Local.Web.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;

namespace Local.Web.Controllers
{
    public class TipSoundController : Controller
    {
        private IRepositorioTipoSonido _repositorioTipoSonido;
        public TipSoundController(IRepositorioTipoSonido repositorioTipoSonido)
        {
            _repositorioTipoSonido = repositorioTipoSonido;
        }
        public IActionResult _TipSounds()
        {
            var tiposSonidos = _repositorioTipoSonido.ListarTodos();
            var model = tiposSonidos.Select(s => new TipSoundModel
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                Tipo = s.Tipo,
                Nombre_ES = s.Nombre_ES,
            });

            return PartialView(model);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the partial view **_Sounds** that shows a list with sounds and types of sounds in which the @foreach problem is. As if it came empty.

```
@model IEnumerable<Local.Web.Models.SoundModel>
@{
    if (ViewData.TryGetValue("ParentLayout", out var parentLayout))
    {
        Layout = (string)parentLayout;
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}


<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sound.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sound.Nombre)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sound.Tipo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tipSound.Nombre_ES)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var item in Model)  // This is the ERROR line
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.sound.Id
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.sound.Nombre
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.sound.Tipo
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.tipSound.Nombre_ES
            </td>
        </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I hide the foreach part and run it, the table captions @ Html.DisplayNameFor (model => model.sound ...) read and display correctly. If I leave the foreach it gives me the typical **System.NullReferenceException error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' pointing to foreach line**

Can someone guide me, because if I show each model in their view, it works fine, but when I show part of the two models in the same view, it is when it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass data with type `List<SoundModel>` to partial view.So you need to change

```
@model Local.Web.Models.SoundModel
```

to

```
@model IEnumerable<Local.Web.Models.SoundModel>
```

in your **Index** View.
And then you need to pass a list in Index action.(I pass a new list to test,you can also pass other data with type `List<SoundModel>`)

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new List<SoundModel>());
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Yiyi You,   I have made the changes, now it does not give an error, but it does not work correctly. The foreach listing @ item.soun.Id, @ item.tipSound ... does not appear. Only the headers of the @ Html.DisplayNameFor are displayed. (Id, Name, Type and Name_ES).

Comment: Yes,if you want to use `<partial name="_Sounds" />` in Index.cshtml,you need to pass the list in Index action as I shown in my answer.My demo is passing a new List<SoundModel>() to view,so there will not shown any data,you can pass your data to view.

Comment: I have made the changes. I have put the new List <SoundModel>() in the index.cshtml, but it still doesn't work. There are more than 30 records in the database. If I get a direct listing from a single model to a single view it works correctly and show the name of the records and the records list, but with this solution that I must show the list of two models in a single view, it only shows the names of the records, like the result photo that you added. But the list of records in the db does not show them. I do not understand what happens. It is as if the model arrived empty.

Comment: You only use `<partial name="_Sounds" />` once,so it will only show one  list.

Comment: Possibly I am not explaining myself correctly. Only the Html.DisplayNameFor of each record appears, but the list with the @items of the foreach does not appear in the table and the list of all the records would have to appear.

Comment: As I mentioned above,don't use `return View(new List<SoundModel>());`  as I shown in my answer,it's just tell you you need to pass a list to view,and you need to pass the data which you get from your db.Since I don't have data from db,so I use a new list with no data to be shown as  a demo.

Comment: This does not work. When I delete new List <SoundModel> () it gives the error again System.NullReferenceException in the @foreach (var item in Model) line

Comment: You misunderstand what I said,I mean give data to the list,without give a list which has no data,for example,`new List<SoundModel>{new SoundModel{...},new SoundModel{...}...}`.Get the list from your db,and pass it to the view.

Comment: Perfect YiYi You. Now I understand you. Sorry, but I'm new to programming and I don't speak English properly either. I'll try this and tell you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly I am not explaining myself correctly.
After making the modifications commented by ***Yiyi You***,

1. Change `@model Local.Web.Models.SoundModel` to `@model IEnumerable<Local.Web.Models.SoundModel>` in the  **Index View**
2. Then, i put `return View(new List<SoundModel>());` in the `IActionResult Index()` of **SoundController**

So, the **System.NullReferenceException error has disappeared**, but it is not working properly.

It only shows the names of the db records, but **does not show the content of the db records** that should be read with the `foreach (var item in Model)`

This is what it shows:

[image]

But it should show this:
[image]